# Rails Edit Form Which Includes Checkboxes on a M:M Assocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Issues:

- Have the checkboxes be checked with what is saved in the database table on first display of the Edit form.
- Have the checkboxes be checked via params on consecutive displays of the Edit form. Like when validation errors are shown.

My solution feels like a hack. Within `edit.html.erb` file I am using an if statement to determine which way to check the checkboxes. Is there a better way to code this?

This is a Rails 7 application.

Thank you -Chris

experience_requests_controller.rb

```rb
def edit
  @experience_request = ExperienceRequest.find(params[:id])
end
```

edit.html.erb (View page)

```rb
  <%= form_with(model: experience_request) do |f| %>
  ...
    <p><span class="required">*</span> What are your preferred pronouns?</p>

    <% if params[:experience_request] %>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:preferred_pronoun_ids, PreferredPronoun.all, :id, :value) do |value| %>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <%= value.label { value.check_box(checked: params[:experience_request] ? params[:experience_request][:preferred_pronoun_ids].include?(value.object.id.to_s) : false) + ' ' + value.text } %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:preferred_pronoun_ids, PreferredPronoun.all, :id, :value) do |value| %>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <%= value.label { value.check_box(checked: experience_request.preferred_pronouns.map(&:id).include?(value.object.id)) + ' ' + value.text } %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  ...
  <% end %>
```

experience_request.rb (Model)

```rb
class ExperienceRequest < ApplicationRecord
  # M:M Association
  has_many :exp_requests_n_pref_pronouns, foreign_key: :experience_request_id, inverse_of: :experience_request
  has_many :preferred_pronouns, :through => :exp_requests_n_pref_pronouns
end
```

exp_requests_n_pref_pronouns.rb (Model)

```rb
class ExpRequestsNPrefPronoun < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :experience_request
  belongs_to :preferred_pronoun
end
```

preferred_pronoun.rb (Model)

```rb
class PreferredPronoun < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :exp_requests_n_pref_pronouns, foreign_key: :preferred_pronoun_id, inverse_of: :preferred_pronoun
  has_many :experience_requests, :through => :exp_requests_n_pref_pronouns
end
```

Snapshot of checkboxes

[image]

Comment: Have a look at simple_form.  It can do collections of check boxes for associations with just one line.

Comment: it seems like this should be radio buttons not checkboxes, b/c only one of the options should be selected, isn't that true? With checkboxes, any or all of the boxes may be checked. With radio buttons only one is checked.

Comment: @LesNightingill The stakeholder wants the employee to be able to select multiple pronouns.